# Outlook 2013 standard reminder does not work correctly on double click

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

in Outlook 2013 I can set a standard reminder of 15 minutes in the settings. This does work if I create a new calender item via menu.
But if I open the calender and double click on a date to create an appointment the reminder box is always set to none.

Does anyone have the same problem or know a solution how to fix it?
(Maybe I missed a setting?)
Because usually I create new items via double click and I want to have a reminder set automatically.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the VBA solution presented here: http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/calendar/calendar-reminders-outlook-2013